# How to use inflater method within the fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-inflate

Hi I am working with android.I had tried to inflate a layout into the fragment, but it shows error in the code "method getLayoutInflater() is undefined for the class". how can I access layout within the fragments ??? please help me I am new to android .Thanks

here is my code

```
        View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
         listView1.addHeaderView(header);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getLayoutInflater()` is a method of `Context`

use `getActivity().getLayoutInflater()`... valid after `onAttach()` call back is called in `Fragment`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are calling this inside of an Activity. Try doing

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View header = li.inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
```

If, on the other hand, you're calling this from a custom adapter, you will need to pass either the LayoutInflater, or the Context variable to the adapter.

Adapter:

```
class MyCustomAdapter{
LayoutInflater li;
    public MyCustomAdapter (LayoutInflater li) {
        layoutInflater = li;
    }
    //...
}
```

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
//...
    public void onCreate() {
        MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        listView.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);
    }
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                R.layout.your_layout, null);
```

Full code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
            R.layout.your_layout, null);
    return view;
}
```